# "Друг напротив друга" или нет?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильнее сказать: "напротив друг друга" или "друг напротив друга"? Или это равноценные выражения?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Грамота" признает варианты равноправными. Лично мне вариант "друг против друга" кажется предпочтительней. Сравните: друг перед другом, друг за другом, друг напротив друга. Хотя пытаюсь сказать, а  автоматически получается наоборот: напротив друг друга. Наверное, потому, что хочется подчеркнуть слово "напротив", а "друг друга" - сливается в некое единство.

Answer (score 1):

А как будет правильно: построил дом напротив дома или построил напротив дом дома?
Смешно, ага. Конечно, можно сказать *построил напротив дома дом*, но это равносильно *сидит напротив друга друг*, а не *сидят друзья напротив друг друга*.

Comment: У Вас мощный интеллект!

Comment: Если у вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/43072)

Answer (score 0):

1. "*Как правильнее сказать: "напротив друг друга" или "друг напротив друга"?*" Правильно и то и другое, смотря, что Вы хотите сказать.
2. "*Или это равноценные выражения?*" Нет, выражения не равноценные. Например. Враги уселись напротив друг друга.
   Дома стояли напротив друг друга.
   Но только друзья могут усесться друг напротив друга.
   Враги могут усесться только враг напротив врага.

**напротив друг друга** - это значит некие объекты расположены лицевой (фасадной) стороной один к другому.
**друг напротив друга** - это значит, что друзья расположены лицом один к другому.